# C - fwrite() not outputting to file

Tags: c, file, fwrite

Never used fwrite(), so I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong. I'm just testing it now and all I want to do is try to write a single char out to a file until it reaches the end. The file I'm writing to is one I downloaded from my teacher's website. When I check the properties of it, the type is only listed as "file". It's supposed to just be an empty 2MB file for us to write our code to (file system lab if anyone's wondering). Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char c;
    FILE *fp;   
    char testing[2] = {'c'};  

    fp = fopen("Drive2MB", "rw"); 

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);     //make sure pointers at beginning of file
    while((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
    {
        fwrite(testing, 1, sizeof(testing), fp);
        fseek(fp, 1, SEEK_CUR);  //increment pointer 1 byte
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

When I run this, an error message pops up saying "Debug Assertion Failed!...Expression:("Invalid file open mode",0) and prints "The program '[3896] filesystem.exe: Native' has exited with code 3 (0x3)."

Comment: I hope it's a lab on how to use file systems as opposed to how to design them. Because you really should know how to use a file system before even trying to design or even implement one... (And the fact that your teacher felt the need to provide you with an empty file scares me)

Comment: not this specifically, but I will be using fwrite in a homework

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have opened the file for reading (that's what the `r` stands for in `fopen("Drive2MB", "r");`). You may not write to a file opened for reading.

Comment: Doh, a stupid mistake, but unfortunately rw doesn't work either. It gives me an error message "Debug Assertion Failed! .... Expression: ("Invalid file open mode",0) and then prints "The program '[3896] filesystem.exe: Native' has exited with code 3 (0x3)."

Comment: @Anon: There's no such mode as `rw`, it's either `r+` or `w+` depending on what you want to do.

Comment: You shouldn't really be trying to read and write to the same file at the same time anyway. The robust way is to read the file into memory, make changes to the memory, and then write it all back. That's assuming you actually care about reading anything; it sounds like you just want to know the file size. There are better ways to go about that. BTW, any write or read operation automatically advances the file position by the corresponding amount - that's why they're called file **streams** (not sure if you've heard the term; it's more of a C++ thing).

Comment: @Karl: I'm not sure "robust" is the right word, because that's the very thing that makes things break when you throw unexpectedly large files at them. And I'd imagine something that simulates a file system should be able to handle files of very large sizes, because they simulate partitions. Of course for small amounts, you could just run the simulation in memory, but it might be nice to be able to try your code on large filesystems as well.

Comment: I added fseek when I was playing around with it, didn't really think I needed it. I'm using w+ now and I don't get an abort message now, but it's still printing a message after it runs "The program '[920] filesystem.exe: Native' has exited with code 0 (0x0)." and the file I'm writing to still contains nothing (I'm opening it in notepad. the only difference I've noticed is now I can't scroll over anymore to the right)

Comment: @Anon: What is this course you're going to take about exactly?

Comment: Get a hex editor so you can study binary files properly. :) `has exited with code 0 (0x0)` means that the program ended without crashing, and the value `0` was returned from the `main` function (which is generally speaking what you want to happen). Anyway, like I said, measure the file size first. For example, open the file for reading, seek to the end, observe the position of the file pointer (with `ftell`); close it again and re-open for writing. Alternatively, you can use the `stat` function from `sys/stat.h`, if your system provides it. BTW, you should be opening everything in binary mode.

Comment: Thanks :) I tried w+ and wb+ and it kept setting the size of the file to 0 (didn't realize until now the open group page says w and wb set truncate the file to 0 if it already exists). I felt like an idiot for using "r" but I think I meant to use "r+" or "rb+". The file isn't being truncated now haha, but still nothing being written : (

Comment: >_< Pay attention. Do it in two steps. Measure the file size, and then re-open for writing, and write the corresponding amount of data. Yes, it truncates the file to 0, but then you append the same amount of data that was there before. This is much easier.

Comment: I didn't see a need to do ftell before since I knew the file size, but I tried what you said, and despite the fact that the file is currently much larger than it should be, ftell returned the expected value (before I reopened it) and I was able to write out, so thank you very much.

Comment: Great! Now recover the original file and try it again. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're opening it in read only mode

Use r+ for the fopen

Answer (score 0):

```
fp = fopen("Drive2MB", "r")
```

your openning your file in read only

try

```
fp = fopen("Drive2MB", "r+");
```

Comment: oups my bad, mixed up languages again sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You've opened the file for reading with the "r" part of fopen. To write to the file, you can open it in read/write mode or write mode.

```
// Read/write mode
fp = fopen("Drive2MB", "r+");

// Write only mode
fp = fopen("Drive2MB", "w");
```

I never like to use "rw" personally. When you open a file, it really should have one reason to be opened. You also do not need to call fseek to move to the start of the file and you do not need to use fseek to advance the file pointer. fopen will automatically open it to the start of the file and fwrite will automatically advance the pointer. fseek should only be used if you are "seek"ing inside of the file to get to a specific point.

In the case you've given, you would only need write ("w") mode since you are not ever reading from the file.

Comment: There's no such open mode as `"rw"`. That would be an illegal combination of modes for `fopen` function. To open a file for both reading and writing `"r+"` mode is used.

Comment: Whoops, I just assumed it existed based on another post. I'll change that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use fopen r+ or w+ to open the file.
2. Use fflush to flush data to disk after fwrite is complete.
3. Use ferror to check if there is any problem with the file stream after fwrite is complete.
4. Check whether the disk has enough free space.

I solved the problem with 3, 4.